# Scatter color map based on a list different from x and y (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Imagine you have the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 1, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0, 0.5, 1.3, 0.1]
y = [0.5, 0.12, 0.45, 0.98, 1.31, 1.87, 1.0, 0.11, 1.45, 0.67]
r = [x[i]/y[i] for i in range(len(x))]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, tight_layout=True, figsize=(10,10))
ax.subplot(x,y,cmap=?)
```

Now I would like to plot this and have a color map. However, the colors of the points are given by the values of r. How do I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 1, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0, 0.5, 1.3, 0.1]
y = [0.5, 0.12, 0.45, 0.98, 1.31, 1.87, 1.0, 0.11, 1.45, 0.67]
r = [x[i]/y[i] for i in range(len(x))]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, tight_layout=True, figsize=(10,10))
ax.scatter(x, y, c=r)
```

You can also change the default colormap

```
ax.scatter(x, y, c=r, cmap='viridis')
```

The complete color map [reference](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use MatPlotLib's [pyplot.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter), which takes 2 arrays (x values, y values) as required arguments. You can also supply a 3rd array, c, of the same length of x and y that sets the color value of each point.

In your case:

```
ax.scatter(x=x,y=y,c=r)
```

easy as that!